# lvm disk corrupt after force power down

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

I have virtual machine running on kvm host.
But after force shutdown (unplugged  power supply of physical server), virtual disk corrupted, cannot boot to OS (OS: CentOS 32bit, include 2 partition, vda1 for /boot - ext3, vda2 using lvm, 1 for swap 1 for / root).
Virtual disk format in qcow2.
I attach that disk in to other virtual machine, new device is vdb (include vdb1 and vdb2)
Ater fsck vdb1, this partition fix but loss grub.
I scan volume group to detech VG of vdb2, but have nothing. After that, I dump some sector to view lvm metadata with command:

```
dd if=/dev/vdb2 bs=512 count=255 skip=1 of=/root/lvmmetadata
```

there are nothing in that file (named lvmmetadata), I think that sector corrupted.

I have use TeskDisk tool (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Compilation) to recovery data
testdisk detect vdb2 using LVM2, but cannot enter to it (error No Volume group found)
How can I recovery my data in vdb2 partition?
please help me resolve this problem.
Thank you so much

Comment: Restore from your backup.

Comment: I have not any backup

Comment: Then you send your disk to a professional data recovery company, and hope that they will get something back. Also you should make sure your CV is up to date.